# material-ui : Extract color from theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use a color from my `material-ui` theme inside a component like that :

```
const MyComponent = props => (
   <UsersIcon color={currentTheme.primary1Color} />
)
```

So, my need is to extract a value from the current provided theme.

I found a working solution to solve this case, using context to retrieve the current theme :

```
const MyComponent = (props, {muiTheme}) => (
    <UsersIcon color={muiTheme.palette.primary1Color} />
)
contextTypes = {
    muiTheme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```

The `React` context is used "under the hood" by `material-ui`, so my solution is not future proof – the implementation of `MUI` can change –, is there any way to solve this in a proper (or recommended) way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have! using muiThemeable..

```
import muiThemeable from 'material-ui/styles/muiThemeable';
const MyComponent = props => (
   <UsersIcon color={props.muiTheme.palette.primary1Color} />
)
export default muiThemeable()(MyComponent )
```

[from material-ui docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes)

Answer (score 10):

You can [access](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component) the theme variables with react `hook` or with `higher-order` component.

Example with hook:

```js
//...
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    return <UsersIcon color={theme.palette.primary.main} />
}
```

Example with HOC:

```js
//...
import { withTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const MyComponent = ({theme, ...other}) => {
    return <UsersIcon color={theme.palette.primary.main} />
}

export default withTheme(MyComponent)
```

Don't forget to wrap root application component with `ThemeProvider`

Another method to mention is `makeStyles` for `CSS-in-JS` styling:

```js
//...
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  icon: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main
  }
}))

const MyComponent = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return <UsersIcon className={classes.icon} />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your colors don't change at runtime, you can store these constants in a global object that gets used to initialize the theme as well as used in your custom components. This would allow you to not depend on context while keeping your code dry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree with you it's a clean way to solve my case. But the way the theming is described by the api let guess themes can be dynamic. I want to find a solution more "future proof" (not sure it exists...)