# Reference to theme's primary color instead of a specific color in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using ReactJS and Material UI, I have a project in which I have changed the theme colors.

```
const newTheme = getMuiTheme({
    fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
    palette: {
        primary1Color: cyan500,
        primary2Color: cyan700,
        primary3Color: grey400,
        accent1Color: amberA400,
        accent2Color: grey100,
        accent3Color: grey500,
        textColor: darkBlack,
        alternateTextColor: white,
        canvasColor: white,
        borderColor: grey300,
        disabledColor: fade(darkBlack, 0.3),
        pickerHeaderColor: cyan500,
        clockCircleColor: fade(darkBlack, 0.07),
        shadowColor: fullBlack,
    },
});

  // App class
  render() {
    return(
        <ThemeProvider theme={newTheme}>
            <Project />
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
```

Everything works as expected. Certain components, like buttons have the ability to set the color based on the primary prop. However, I have a component that uses an icon that needs the primary color. I can import the color and set it directly:

```
import React from 'react';
import ActionLock from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/lock';
import {cyan500} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';

export default class LockIcon extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <ActionLock color={cyan500} />
        )
    }
}
```

Is there some way to reference the theme's primary color, rather than setting the color in each component individually? Something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ActionLock from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/lock';
import {primary1Color} from 'somewhere';

export default class LockIcon extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <ActionLock color={primary1Color} />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [material-ui : Extract color from theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169520/material-ui-extract-color-from-theme)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you have!
using  muiThemeable..

```
import muiThemeable from 'material-ui/styles/muiThemeable';
class LockIcon extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <ActionLock color={this.props.muiTheme.palette.primary1Color} />
        )
    }
}
        export default muiThemeable()(LockIcon)
```

[from material-ui docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes)

Answer (score 48):

If you're using React v16.8.0 and Material-UI v3.5.0 or greater, you can utilize the `useTheme()` hook:

```
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

function LockIcon = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <ActionLock color={theme.palette.primary1Color} />
}
```

Comment: The use of this hook is still used in `@mui/material` > 5.1.1.  However, the palette shape has changed a little.  `theme.palette.main.info` for example.

Comment: As lower answers say, using MUI v5 `import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";` then `const theme = useTheme();` then `color={theme.palette.primary.main}`

Answer (score 15):

Adding how to access theme colors in [material-ui **v1.0.0**](https://material-ui-next.com/style/color/) (currently beta) Using **withTheme** component.
Also check the following [Example](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/6f815c5cda5d4a53cdfed34777ef1da1706ba903/docs/src/pages/customization/WithTheme.js).

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { withTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';

class WithThemeExample extends Component {
    render() {
        const { theme } = props;
        const {primary, secondary} = theme.palette.text;

        return (
            <div>
                <div style={{color: primary}}>Hi in Primary color</div>
                <div style={{color: secondary}}>Bye in Secondary color</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withTheme()(WithThemeExample);
```

Comment: where is props coming from?

Comment: the "withTheme" component is injecting the colors to the "WithThemeExample" component

Comment: `withTheme` expects a function, not a `class`. The original post implies implementation inside the class.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using [system properties](https://mui.com/system/properties), you can define a string path of the [`Palette`](https://mui.com/system/palette/) object to the color value like below:

```html
<Box sx={{ color: "primary.main" }}>primary.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: "secondary.main" }}>secondary.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: "error.main" }}>error.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: "warning.main" }}>warning.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: "info.main" }}>info.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: "success.main" }}>success.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: "text.primary" }}>text.primary</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: "text.secondary" }}>text.secondary</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: "text.disabled" }}>text.disabled</Box>
```

The above is the same as:

```
<Box sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.primary.main }}>primary.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.secondary.main }}>secondary.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.error.main }}>error.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.warning.main }}>warning.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.info.main }}>info.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.success.main }}>success.main</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.text.primary }}>text.primary</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.text.secondary }}>text.secondary</Box>
<Box sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.text.disabled }}>text.disabled</Box>
```

The example using the callback is more verbose but is type-safe, the shorter one with only string is quicker and good when prototyping, but you may want to store the string in a constant to prevent any typo errors and help the IDE refactor your code better.

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 43281020/reference-to-themes-primary-color-instead-of-a-specific-color-in-material-ui]

Comment: upvote as your answer is solution for mui 5 (currently beta), cheers!

Comment: @Chiu MUI v5 is released [now](https://mui.com/blog/mui-core-v5/)

Comment: wao thanks man for this solution. i was thinking maybe something wrong with my custom theme file code. how simple it was. before i was trying to access like this by importing my custom theme
color:  theme.palette.primary.main
it was really simple according to your solution. simple     color: "primary.contrastText",
i was stuck in this issue from yesterday. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use the useTheme() hook and access the colors like the example below.
There are also some other color variants as well.

[image]

Mui 5:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

function VinNavLink(props) {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <NavLink {...props} style={({ isActive }) => isActive ? { textDecoration: "underline", color: theme.palette.primary.main} : undefined}>{props.children}</NavLink>
  );
}

export default VinNavLink;
```

Answer (score 5):

With react hooks, now you don't need to warp component in **withTheme**,  just use **useTheme**:

```
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default function MyComponent() {
    const theme = useTheme();
    
    return <span>{`spacing ${theme.spacing}`}</span>;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok if you are using material-ui version greater than 4, then the above solution might not work for you. Follow the below's code

```
import { withTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

function DeepChildRaw(props) {
  return <span>{`spacing ${props.theme.spacing}`}</span>;
}

const DeepChild = withTheme(DeepChildRaw);
```

Reference: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/

Answer (score 4):

### MUI V5

For the users of MUI v5, you can specify a function inside the `sx` css style directly, ex:

```
<Box sx={{ color: (theme) => theme.palette.primary1Color }} />
```

Answer (score 1):

With MUI 5 and the `createTheme()` function, you can reference the palette inside your `ThemeOptions` by passing a function as the `typography` value. This function accepts the palette as it's first argument.

This lets you easily map the various hX and bodyX typography variants.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#2D3178",
    },
  },
  typography: (palette) => ({
    h1: {
      fontSize: "2rem",
      fontWeight: 700,
      color: palette.primary.main,
    },
  }),
});
```

You can also reference the theme in the `sx` prop by passing a function

```
<Box sx={(theme) => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
})}/>
```