# using default theme colors material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how to use default theme colors like "primary" or "secondary" in sx property? I don't want to change them, I just want to write sx={{ backgroundColor: "primary" }} or smth like that

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69234401/9449426) answer for v5.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a bit more specific which color you want:

For example to access priamry.main, use:

```
<Box sx={{ borderColor: 'primary.main' }} />
```

or for the current text color:

```
<Box sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}>Sessions</Box>
```

More [information](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#theme-aware-properties)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Can you describe that in more detail or show an example codesandbox. Maybe look into the console. Is your app wrapped in a themeprovider? And do you use mui v5?

Comment: now that I wrapped my components in themeprovider it causes an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fontWeightBold')"

Comment: Did you add a theme to it? Can you maybe share some of your code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-bogdan-41bz7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You are using material-ui v4 but you need to [upgrade to mui v5](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/) since its only supported by the new version. Any you need to supply a theme instead of passing an empty object

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-agnesi-tzkdu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: in my project (not sandbox) I have @material-ui/core 5.0.0-beta.5. I installed it following documentation and I can't import @mui/material/styles because I just don't have it

Comment: Remove material-ui and install mui material. And use this

Comment: @fpetrakov see the installation guide [here](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/#npm), don't use `@material-ui/..` packages for v5, use `@mui/...`